# KeyError reverse HashMap - Python Simple Collaborative KNN Model

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, hashmap, knn

I'm having this problem with my recommender. For some of the beers I want recommendations for it works perfectly but sometimes it returns a KeyError. I have no idea why this happens?

Always happens when trying to recommend for the same item so it has probably something to do with the hashmap code or the reverse hashmap.

[Picture of KeyError while running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHVcK.png)

**Picture of **

**Code**

```
import os
import time
import gc
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

class KnnRecommender:
    """
    This is an item based collaborative filtering recommender with KNN implemented by sklearn
    """
    def __init__(self, path_beers, path_tastingprofiles):
        """
        Recommender requires path to data: movies data and ratings data
        Parameters
        ----------
        path_movies: str, movies data file path
        path_ratings: str, ratings data file path
        """
        self.path_beers = path_beers
        self.path_tastingprofiles = path_tastingprofiles
        self.model = NearestNeighbors()

    def set_model_params(self, n_neighbors, algorithm, metric, n_jobs=None):
        """
        set model params for sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors
        Parameters
        ----------
        n_neighbors: int, optional (default = 5)
        algorithm: {'auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute'}, optional
        metric: string or callable, default 'minkowski', or one of
            ['cityblock', 'cosine', 'euclidean', 'l1', 'l2', 'manhattan']
        n_jobs: int or None, optional (default=None)
        """
        if n_jobs and (n_jobs > 1 or n_jobs == -1):
            os.environ['JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER'] = '/tmp'
        self.model.set_params(**{
            'n_neighbors': n_neighbors,
            'algorithm': algorithm,
            'metric': metric,
            'n_jobs': n_jobs})

    def _prep_data(self):
        """
        prepare data for recommender
        1. beer-tastingprofile scipy sparse matrix
        2. hashmap of beer to row index in beer-tastingprofile scipy sparse matrix
        """
        # read data
        df_beers = pd.read_csv(
            os.path.join(self.path_beers),
            usecols=['beerID', 'name', 'beertypeID'],
            dtype={'beerID': 'int32', 'name': 'str', 'beerID': 'int32'})
        df_tastingprofiles = pd.read_csv(
            os.path.join(self.path_tastingprofiles),
            usecols=['beerID', 'malty', 'sweet', 'sour', 'hoppy', 'bitter', 'fruity'],
            dtype={'beerID': 'int32', 'malty': 'float32', 'sweet': 'float32', 'sour': 'float32', 'hoppy': 'float32', 'bitter': 'float32', 'fruity': 'float32'})


        #filtering beers/removing unprofiled beers
        df_beers_merged = pd.merge(df_tastingprofiles, df_beers, on='beerID')
        df_beers = df_beers_merged.drop(['malty', 'sweet', 'sour', 'hoppy', 'bitter', 'fruity'], axis=1)

        # pivot and create tastingprofile matrix
        df_tastingprofile_features = df_tastingprofiles.set_index('beerID')

        # create mapper from beer name to index
        hashmap = {
            beer: i for i, beer in
            enumerate(list(df_beers.set_index('beerID').loc[df_tastingprofile_features.index].name)) # noqa
        }

        #converting tastingprofile features to scipy sparse matrix
        mat_tastingprofile_features = csr_matrix(df_tastingprofile_features.values)


        # clean up
        del df_beers, df_beers_merged
        del df_tastingprofiles, df_tastingprofile_features
        return mat_tastingprofile_features, hashmap

    def _fuzzy_matching(self, hashmap, fav_beer):
        """
        return the closest match via fuzzy ratio.
        If no match found, return None
        Parameters
        ----------
        hashmap: dict, map beer name to index of the beer in data
        fav_beer: str, name of user input beer
        Return
        ------
        index of the closest match
        """
        match_tuple = []
        # get match
        for name, idx in hashmap.items():
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(name.lower(), fav_beer.lower())
            if ratio >= 60:
                match_tuple.append((name, idx, ratio))
        # sort
        match_tuple = sorted(match_tuple, key=lambda x: x[2])[::-1]
        if not match_tuple:
            print('Oops! No match is found')
        else:
            print('Found possible matches in our database: '
                  '{0}\n'.format([x[0] for x in match_tuple]))
            return match_tuple[0][1]

    def _inference(self, model, data, hashmap,
                   fav_beer, n_recommendations):
        """
        return top n similar beer recommendations based on user's input movie
        Parameters
        ----------
        model: sklearn model, knn model
        data: beer-tastingprofile matrix
        hashmap: dict, map beer name to index of the mobeervie in data
        fav_beer: str, name of user input beer
        n_recommendations: int, top n recommendations
        Return
        ------
        list of top n similar beer recommendations
        """
        # fit
        model.fit(data)
        # get input movie index
        print('You have input movie:', fav_beer)
        idx = self._fuzzy_matching(hashmap, fav_beer)
        # inference
        print('Recommendation system start to make inference')
        print('......\n')
        t0 = time.time()
        distances, indices = model.kneighbors(
            data[idx],
            n_neighbors=n_recommendations+1)
        # get list of raw idx of recommendations
        raw_recommends = \
            sorted(
                list(
                    zip(
                        indices.squeeze().tolist(),
                        distances.squeeze().tolist()
                    )
                ),
                key=lambda x: x[1]
            )[:0:-1]
        print('It took my system {:.2f}s to make inference \n\
              '.format(time.time() - t0))
        # return recommendation (movieId, distance)
        return raw_recommends

    def make_recommendations(self, fav_beer, n_recommendations):
        """
        make top n beer recommendations
        Parameters
        ----------
        fav_beer: str, name of user input beer
        n_recommendations: int, top n recommendations
        """
        # get data
        mat_tastingprofile_features, hashmap = self._prep_data()
        # get recommendations
        raw_recommends = self._inference(
            self.model, mat_tastingprofile_features, hashmap,
            fav_beer, n_recommendations)
        # print results
        reverse_hashmap = {v: k for k, v in hashmap.items()}
        print('Recommendations for {}:'.format(fav_beer))
        for i, (idx, dist) in enumerate(raw_recommends):
            #reverse_hashmap[idx]
            print('{0}: {1}, with distance of {2}'.format(i+1,reverse_hashmap[idx], dist))

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog="Beer Recommender",
        description="Run KNN Beer Recommender")
    parser.add_argument('--path', nargs='?', default='',
                         help='input data path')
    parser.add_argument('--beer_filename', nargs='?', default='beer.csv',
                        help='provide beer filename')
    parser.add_argument('--tastingprofile_filename', nargs='?', default='tastingprofile.csv',
                        help='provide tastingprofile filename')
    parser.add_argument('--beer_name', nargs='?', default='',
                        help='provide your favorite beer name')
    parser.add_argument('--top_n', type=int, default=10,
                        help='top n beer recommendations')
    return parser.parse_args()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get args
    args = parse_args()
    data_path = args.path
    beer_filename = args.beer_filename
    tastingprofile_filename = args.tastingprofile_filename
    beer_name = args.beer_name
    top_n = args.top_n
    # initial recommender system
    recommender = KnnRecommender(
    os.path.join(data_path, beer_filename),
    os.path.join(data_path, tastingprofile_filename))
    recommender.set_model_params(20, 'brute', 'cosine', -1)
    # make recommendations
    recommender.make_recommendations(beer_name, top_n)
```

Comment: It seems that you have KeyError in `reverse_hashmap[idx]`. It's hard to say what goes wrong in your code without context, but I suggest you to change it to be `reverse_hashmap.get(idx, 'NO DATA')` for debugging purpose.

Comment: @SergeyPugach If you want I can add some context, what would you like to know? The system should recommend beers based on the data I'm putting in. It uses the hashmap to get the names back. But with some beers it gives the KeyError.

Debugging wise I've already found what the problem is. The key isn't in my hashmap. But I don't know where he gets this key?

Another thing, this is code I found and edited. Most of it I do understand but I cannot seem to find where he gets that key from, since it's not in my hashmap.

Comment: @SergeyPugach I did some digging in the code it seems that there's something wrong when I populate my hashmap with the data. I have 2888 tastingprofiles. But the hashmap only has 2369 values. So I might be doing something wrong there. This is all very new to me so I might be overlooking something stupid.

Comment: [ExtraPicture](https://gyazo.com/6b079db59eb6f7aa57f1285c3605c8f8)
[ExtraPicture2](https://gyazo.com/61b95fd41183f779e6727c65d5c38d10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
Figured out that when I use the names as values in a Hashmap the duplicates automatically get removed. So the hashmap was smaller than the full db list. I solved it by removing the duplicates in my dataset before using it for anything in the recommendation algorithm.

I'll show you my simple fix with pandas Dataframes merging and drop_duplicates.

```
#Remove duplicates from Beers dataset
        df_beers_noduplicates = df_beers.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='first', inplace=False)
        df_beers_merged = pd.merge(df_tastingprofiles, df_beers_noduplicates, on='beerID')
        df_beers = df_beers_merged.drop(['malty', 'sweet', 'sour', 'hoppy', 'bitter', 'fruity'], axis=1)
        df_tastingprofiles = df_beers_merged.drop(['name'], axis=1)
```